# Shell Script - Alert if netstat output does not exal 0 for all lines

Tags: bash, shell, netstat

How can I look at the output of the third column in netstat -an results and if any line does not equal 0 then alert.

For Example

```
netstat -an|grep 100|awk '{print $3}'
0
0
0
2322
0
0
4344
0
```

Should result in `"Alert, netstat is showing 2 numbers greater than zero"`

I'm just trying to alert if any row is something other than 0.

Thanks!

Comment: Adding `| grep -vc '^0$'` will give you the number of lines of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined with AlexP's answer, you'll get:

```
if [ $(netstat -an|grep 100|awk '{print $3}' | grep -vc '^0$') -ge 2 ]; then
    echo "Alert, netstat is showing 2 numbers greater than zero"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks @unwastable ! How do I get it so if the output is 1 ore more send an alert? all connections should be 0.

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: -ge a comparison operator that allows you to check if the output is greater than certain number. If you want a 1 or more use a -ge 1

Comment: Thanks @Unwastable that is exactly what I needed!